# serialize each object in Object collection

Tags: c#, serialization, collections

I have this code for serializing my custom collection of UserData Objects.  However the `current` property only represents the item currently being used in the collection, so it only serializes that one object.

I want all the objects serialized in my collection, how would I go about that in the `GetObjectData` implementation of my Collection?

```
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            // Add the userdata object to SerializationInfo object
                info.AddValue("UserData", current);
        }
```

this is my deserialization constructor, I'm not sure this will then deserialize each object in the collection either.

```
public UserDataCollection(SerializationInfo serializationInfo, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            UserData data = (UserData)serializationInfo.GetValue("UserData", typeof(UserData));
              // Add to objects existing collection
            this.Add(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you holding your objects behind the scenes? Do you have a `List<T>` field somewhere? Just serialize / deserialize that, and let it worry about it. To be honest, this should just *happen* if you mark the custom collection wrapper as `[Serializable]` and mark any unnecessary fields (such as `current`) as `[NonSerialized]` (i.e. without you having to implement `ISerializable`).

Note that in most scenarios I tend to advise *against* `BinaryFormatter`; it is OK for sending short-lived (transient) messages, but I don't advise using it for storage purposes (in a file or in a database); you can get lots of versioning issues trying to deserialize at a later date.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I wondered, what kind of Serialization do you then recommend?  XML?

Comment: It depends what you need. XmlSerializer / DataContractSerializer are ood for xml; json.net is another text-based option. For binary I recommend protobuf-net, but I kinda would... (but it is free...)